# Track errors/crashes in meteor/phonegap/cordova

Tags: cordova, meteor, phonegap-plugins

We are right now trying to figure out how to best track errors and app crashes in our meteor app. If anyone of you already went through this process I would love your input on this. What we found so far:

**kadira.io:** 
Looks good for errors and bottlenecks but does not track app crashes which is a major part of the todo.

**telerik.com:**
Seems to be tracking both errors and crashes. But if you really want to bring it to production the costs per unique active devices really blows up quite fast.

**crittercism.com:**
On first glance it does what it should (did not implement this one just checked out the page) but we stopped as soon as we saw the price modal. Starting at 300$ with only 10k uniques per month.

**airbrake.io:**
Would be my first choice but does not support phonegap and all the wrapper I found seem not very stable and don't track crashes besides errors.

So at this point I will try telerik but would love your optionen. Thanks a ton!

Comment: This question is off-topic for StackOverflow because it asks for directions to off-site resources and opinions on products and services.

Comment: @Kyll relax, it is about what programmers have to do to get the job done. OP is not asking about a 'cloud basket' (app function) but about a logging/crash utility (function of creating an app).

Answer (score 2):

You can try https://www.atatus.com/ which supports meteor/phonegap/cordova apps. It might fit your needs.

Disclaimer: I work at Atatus.